# How to download a generated excel workbook form the server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-poi

I generated a excel file from apache poi on the server. Instead of it write on the server I want to download the file. Following code is writing that file on the server. I want to modify it, In order to download the file directly.

```
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path+"filename.xlsx")) {
    workbook.write(outputStream);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like this

```
public class A extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) {
        // ...
        try {
            rs.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            workbook.write(rs.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        // ...
     }
}
```